# Find either of 2 matched strings in files and print lines using bat

Tags: batch-file

Right now I am able to find matched string(containing more than 1 word) `No active features in part. Skipping.` with one command. I want to modify it further to also extract data(i.e. print lines) if file contains `aborting` word.

```
findstr /C:"No active features in part. Skipping." %ROOT%\RenewAndSaveReport\*.txt >> SkippedParts.txt
```

Comment: Add `/c:"aborting"` either before or after the existing `/c...`

Comment: I would suggest you use, `FindStr/IL /C:"No active features in part. Skipping." /C:"aborting" "%ROOT%\RenewAndSaveReport\*.txt">>"SkippedParts.txt"`.

Comment: @Magoo Thank you, but when tried, there is error that Cannot open C:/aborting

Comment: @Compo Thank you, it's working as expected. Thanks, you can post this as an answer.

Comment: I have one more query. Can we search this/these string in more than one location? I mean can we add 2 paths in a command.

Comment: That's why I said `Add /c:"aborting"` - not my fault if you added `C:/aborting`

Comment: @Magoo, yeah, it's my fault. Actuallly I tried (for other strings) with adding double quote but may be wrong in typing, was not working. Your's is also working fine. Please post your answer too. Sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```bat
FindStr/IL /C:"No active features in part. Skipping." /C:"aborting" "%ROOT%\RenewAndSaveReport\*.txt">>"SkippedParts.txt"
```